# How to properly cache AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, caching

I'm doing some research on how to properly cache AJAX responses, since that speeds up a page with lots of AJAX requests. I found this piece on the Yahoo website:

> Let's look at an example. A Web 2.0 email client might use Ajax to download the user's address book for autocompletion. If the user hasn't modified her address book since the last time she used the email web app, the previous address book response could be read from cache if that Ajax response was made cacheable with a future Expires or Cache-Control header. The browser must be informed when to use a previously cached address book response versus requesting a new one. This could be done by adding a timestamp to the address book Ajax URL indicating the last time the user modified her address book, for example, &t=1190241612. If the address book hasn't been modified since the last download, the timestamp will be the same and the address book will be read from the browser's cache eliminating an extra HTTP roundtrip. If the user has modified her address book, the timestamp ensures the new URL doesn't match the cached response, and the browser will request the updated address book entries.

This makes it only less clear. The reason I want to know all this, is that I'm building a simple webpage where users can add shortcuts to websites. They see a grid of icons and can click on or search for the website they need. This is only meant as a project to get to know PHP and most importantly AJAX a lot better; nothing that actual users will ever see.

As you can imagine, the search function slows the website down a lot. Especially since it's performing an AJAX request after **every** typed letter. Therefore, I think it would greatly improve the website if some parts of this would be cached.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make up your mind first:

Do you want a cached response used, or do you want the server to create a fresh one each time?

It isn't clear to me what you are asking exactly. What do you want to be cached, and how long?

- If you want a cached response, simply use an URL you used before. (In combination with an expires-header)

For example:
http://www.example.com/myAjaxHelper.php?q=ab

If server responds with an expires header that says "one week from now", you will get the cached response for a week. Your browser will make that so.
(Remember YOU can set up the expires value in the response headers)
There are problems with browsers NOT respecting the expires header, and sometimes they fetch the cached version instead of the new one, even if it expired in the past. (Notably older IE needed a few of extra headers to fix that, and it is highly confusing)

- If you want a fresh response (and this can lead to slowness because on each key-up you make a roundtrip to the server), make a NEW url.
  Eg:

  http://www.example.com/myAjaxHelper.php?q=ab?time=< ?php echo time(); ?>

This will lead to a **new** URL each second. And that one will never be cached, because the URL differs (only for the time=.... part, but that is enough to force a new request).